# Several 3-way ANOVA vs one 4-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, experiment-design

I have experiment leading to 4-way ANOVA:

- 3 experimental groups.
- participants in each group responded to 70 trials.
- Reaction time as DV.
- trials were divided into separate groups by full factorial design by three variables A,B and C.

I'm not sure what is the best way to analyze the data. I can run one 4-way ANOVA with (`RT ~ group*A*B*C`) or run three 3-way ANOVAs for each group separately (`RT ~ A*B*C`).

What is the best practice? Run one 4-way ANOVA, but harder to interpret, or run three 3-way ANOVAs and correct for multiple testing?

Comment: Please consider:  if each variable, A, B, and C, had just 2 levels, then there would be 2x2x2=8 groups.  Does this design really have only 3?  And if so, what splits the participants into these 3?  I suspect that where you speak of "variables" you actually have 3 levels of a single variable.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Group is also a variable (with 3 levels), variables A,B and C have 2,2 and 3 levels respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not really interested in the comparison between groups go for the 3-way definitely. The 4-way case will end up with A LOT of interactions for you to study. This is very complex and tiring...

Comment: Thank you, unfornutaly, I'm interested in comparison between groups. Can I run three 3-way anovas and correct for type I error? I'm not sure, how to interpret significant coeficients for higher level interactions.

Comment: So one analysis for each group is not an option. You could remove one of the factors or run the analysis with all 4 of them, selecting what interactions and main effects you think are important to be interpreted.